# 'Including' Grammar

Tags: grammar, descriptive-grammar

> Applicants for this position must have successfully completed Grade 12 or the equivalent including Grade 12 Mathematics, Grade 12 English and 1 senior Science.

Does this mean the applicant will **always** need the 1 senior Science course completed to be eligible? Or is it simply describing the equivalent courses that are needed?

Comment: As I read this, the applicant must have completed Grade 12, which includes Grade 12 Math, Grade 12 English, and various senior sciences.  Since the applicant has to have completed Grade 12, he or she has to have completed all those courses.  However, he or she could have been in an alternate program (i.e. GED) which included instruction at an equivalent level.

Comment: See, I've finished highschool without a senior science credit. So I'm trying to figure out if I'm eligible.

Comment: My interpretation is that you need a senior science credit for this position.  However, it is contradictory, because by the logic of the wording, you shouldn't have been allowed to graduate without that science credit.  In any event, you should apply, since the worst that can happen is that they'll tell you you're not eligible.

Answer (score 1):

Always.  The parsing is:

> Applicants for this position must have successfully completed (Grade 12 or the equivalent), including (Grade 12 Mathematics, Grade 12 English and 1 senior Science)